# How to run gunicorn from 1 folder above manage.py

Tags: javascript, python, docker, console

My folder structure is completely messed up but I am trying to load my django project on to a docker image for the first time and its failing on my CMD step

My directories are as follows:

```
WORKDIR/appname/appname/wsgi.py
```

In my docker image I need to call the gunicorn command that runs the server. Typically when I am in the terminal I can cd into the right directory and run

`gunicorn appname.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`

How can run this same command from 1 folder structure outside of where I normally am?

I have tried `gunicorn ./appname/appname.wsgi:application ...`

Thanks in advance

Do i change the WORKDIR right before the command?

Comment: The last `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile will set the current directory when the `CMD` is eventually run, yes.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] and better describe the actual problem you're having?

Comment: Thank you I have solved my issues with your advice.